# Update encrypted Cookie laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I tried this

```
$value = $request->cookie('AuthCookie');
$cookie->forget('AuthCookie');

$cookie->make('AuthCookie', $username, 44444);
```

But this does not update the cookie and it sometimes crashes.

I am using 5.4 version of laravel.

Comment: try `$request->cookie->forget('AuthCookie')`

Comment: Call to a member function forget() on null - this is the error i get.

Comment: try this: `\Cookie::forget('AuthCookie')`

Comment: its version 5.4

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve `CookieJar` singleton from the container by using:

```
$cookie = resolve('cookie');
$cookie->forget('AuthCookie');
```

References:

- [CookieJar binding to the container](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Cookie/CookieServiceProvider.php#L14)
- [Resolving from the container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#resolving)